# Отобразить дни в календаре взависимости от месяца

Tags: javascript, функции, calendar

Здравствуйте. Работаю над календарем. Застрял на том месте, где нужно отобразить количество дней в зависимости от месяца. Месяца у меня переключаются а количество дней остается неизменной. Не понимаю как это сделать. Буду безумно благодарен за подробное объяснение. Ссылка на календарь     `(http://codepen.io/Ho4ka/pen/PpOgpe`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл

```
    for (var r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        // create cells in row
        for (var c = 0; c < cellsInRow; c++) {
            if (currentnum - start < length) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");

                currentnum += 1;
                if (start < currentnum) {
                   var cellText = document.createTextNode(currentnum - start);
                   cell.appendChild(cellText);
                   cell.classList.add("days");
                }

                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
         }

         tbl.appendChild(row); // add the row to the end of the table body
    }
```

отрисовывает дни один раз при открытии страницы и больше не используется, по нажатию на кнопку не вызывается код отвечающий за обработку отображения дней. Нужно вынести его в функцию, которая будет вызываться при нажатии на кнопку и передавать в нее параметры, типа, года и месяца для которых нужно отобразить дни.

Comment: Простите я совсем новичок. Не могли бы вы мне написать решение моей проблемы и прокомментировать его ?   Я понимаю что это действительно мелочь, но пока мне это тяжело дается.

Comment: Я в целом объяснил в чем проблема, если действительно непонятно о чем я говорю, то либо вы не сами писали код, либо стоит начать изучение js с самоучителя, например https://www.gitbook.com/book/karmazzin/eloquentjavascript_ru/details

Comment: Спасибо и на этом. Наверное мало у меня еще понимание и знаний JS.